# use android gradle plugin 3.0.0 is slower than gradle plugin 2.3.3

Tags: gradle, plugins

when update the  `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3` to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0` , and I find the build-time is longer than 2.3.3 .

the root `build.gradle` is

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

the `app/build.gradle`  is here , and all my dependencies use `compile`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            ...
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "8g"
        keepRuntimeAnnotatedClasses false

    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'org/apache/commons/codec/language/bm/*.txt'
    }
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.1"
 }
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gg.kk"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 512654
        versionName "version"
        multiDexEnabled true

}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    .... many dependencies ....
}
```

can anyone tell me why my build become slow?

Comment: The first build is supposed to be slower since the build caches and downloads the updated files.
Subsequent builds shouldn't be slower imo, maybe an issue related to your system?

Comment: I use gradle 4.1 , the same project and build runtime envirnment, and I build many times without open daemon and parallel .  Every build-cost-time of plugin 3.0.0 is longer than plugin 2.3.3 . I found the build task of plugin 3.0.0 is different of plugin 2.3.3 .  because of that?

Answer (score 0):

Many different things can effect gradle build times.

To decrease this time you may want to try at least one of this solutions:

- Check if [Gradle Deamon](https://blog.gradle.org/unleash-the-daemon) is enabled. It should be enabled by default.
- Keep your Gradle up-to-date (You are already good at this though)
  *you can go /gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties and upgrade gradle version by changing distributionUrl*
- Increase your heapsize

  org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx3072m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
- Enable parallelism in your `gradle.properties` by adding `org.gradle.parallel=true`
- Don't use dynamic dependencies like compile `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'`
- `File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle`
  Check the `'Offline work'` under `'Global Gradle settings'` Short term solution.
- Check this https://developer.android.com/studio/build/optimize-your-build.html

Comment: in order to get a correct test data , I close the daemon and parallel . I use the same project and the same envirnment. I build many times .But the plugin 3.0.0 is always slower than plugin 2.3.3 .